# Error trying to install mongodb with brew

Tags: homebrew

When installing mongodb with brew I get the following error

`Error: An unexpected error occurred during the "brew link" step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
[BorisGrunwald@boriss-mbp Downloads]$`

Anyone know what might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colin, brew not support sudo anymore.

Boris try this:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks
brew link --overwrite python@2
```

Answer (score 0):

brew is not having write permissions for /usr/local directory.
Try changing the permission using below command

sudo chown -R : *

Answer (score 0):

try unsing **sudo** to set the Permissions :

sudo brew install ...